# Правильность Скобок на Python

Tags: python

Помогите написать программу которая будет выводить на экран правильно ли написаны скобки вот пример
"(()(()"
не правильно
"(()(()()))"
правильно.
Скобки нужно вводить с клавиатуры

Comment: Помощь в написании подразумевает, что вы уже что-то пытались сделать. Приведите ваш код, пожалуйста, и скажите, что именно не получается.

Comment: Интересная задача, не будем забирать у вас возможность её решить.

Comment: А `)(` - правильно?

Comment: на будущее - это форум людей, помогающих друг другу, но не в тех случаях, когда за кого то просят что либо решить. либо объясните в чем у вас ошибка, либо go for a walk..

Comment: @0xdb смысл тот же, так что такую формальность можно опустить

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def check():
    br = input("> ")
    count = 0
    for literal in br:
        count += 1 if literal == '(' else -1
        if count < 0:
            return 'Error'
    return 'ok' if count == 0 else 'not ok'
```

Comment: Так уже правильно , за что -2?

Comment: а что если количество скобок то совпадает, но порядок не тот, она все равно выдаст "правильно", хотя не должно..

Comment: как и отметил Евгений, вы проверяете на количество скобок, а потом зачем то, на то, не начинается ли последовательность с "(" и заканчивается ли она "("

Comment: Блин не то скобку поставил , теперь нормально?

Comment: `()` - выводит ошибку

Comment: Вот теперь нормально :)

Comment: Теперь так: ())(() . У вас хорошая идея, но в реализации есть недочет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Как это доделать?

Comment: Я просто уже сталкивался с этой задачей) последовательность одинаковых скобок считается правильной, только если на каждом шаге закрывающих скобок не больше, чем открывающих, а к концу строки их становится поравну. Реализацию можно посмотреть в моём ответе)

Comment: только хотел написать) открывающих может быть сколько угодно, главное чтоб количество закрывающих не превышало их, тогда все будет хорошо

Comment: и все равно будет ошибка))

Comment: правильно делать сразу я не могу, всегда где то да что.. теперь точно ок, не за что)

Answer (score 4):

В правильной строке (если она состоит исключительно из скобок) неизбежно есть последовательность `()`. Будем удалять `()` пока возможно, и если это не приведёт к появлению неправильной строки, то ничего от исходной строки не останется.

```
line = input('enter sample: ')
while '()' in line:
    line = line.replace('()', '')
print('ok' if not line else 'not ok!')
```

Comment: Лучшее решение из всех

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = input("> ")
count = 0
for c in s:
    if c == "(":
        count += 1
    elif c == ")":
        count -= 1
    if count < 0:
        print('Wrong!')
        break
else:
    if count == 0:
        print('Right')
    else:
        print('Wrong!')
```

Comment: Поправьте отступы.

Comment: @Эникейщик в python у `for` и `while` есть блок `else`, который выполняется, если цикл был закончен, а не прерван через `break`. В этой ситуации `else` относится именно к `for`

Comment: Ого, не знал. век живи век учись.

Comment: Можете еще помочь с задачкой

Comment: @Эникейщик конструкция просто странная, очень редко используется..

Comment: @finally обычно в таких задачах используют булеву переменную, которая указывает на то, верна ли ещё последовательность, или уже нет. Но если язык позволяет обойтись без неё, почему бы этим не воспользоваться? Это ведь не `goto`, в конце концов ;)

Comment: python на то и python)